# In which unit the Canvas.Left property is measured?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to know the unit of measurement of the property Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top, since I have the coordinate of a 3D point and I want to scale them.

Comment: @Clemens - to be fair to OP the documentation does not make reference to the units of measurement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WPF supports automatic scaling by using the device independent pixel as its primary unit of measurement, instead of hardware pixels; graphics and text scale properly without any extra work from the application developer.

Device independent pixels/units. You can read more in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-graphics-rendering-overview):